# Unhandled exception at 0x77aa1f38 in xxx.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, directory-listing

I'm trying to show files of a directory recursively but I'm getting a stack overflow error(I'm new to win32API):

> Unhandled exception at 0x77aa1f38 in xxx.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack
>   overflow.

How do I solve that?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

void getAllFiles(TCHAR *target_dir);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    getAllFiles(TEXT(".\\*"));
    getchar();
}

void getAllFiles(TCHAR *target_dir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError = 0;

    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, target_dir);
    hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

    if(hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("FindFirstFile");
        return;
    }

    do
    {

            if(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if(_tccmp(ffd.cFileName, TEXT(".")) && _tccmp(ffd.cFileName, TEXT("..")))
                {
                    getAllFiles(ffd.cFileName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), ffd.cFileName);
            }

   }
   while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

   dwError = GetLastError();
   if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
   {
      printf("FindFirstFile\n");
   }
    FindClose(hFind);
 }
```

Comment: Being new, forget about `TCHAR` and use wide strings to interact with the winapi.

Comment: Isn't `TCHAR` a wide string if _UNICODE macro is defined?

Comment: Stack overflow is almost always due to "infinite" recursion.

Comment: `UNICODE`, yes, but `TCHAR` is really only there for compatibility with super old versions of Windows. It's a hindrance to new programs.

Comment: @chris, if a binary is built with `UNICODE`, what's the oldest ver of Windows that it will run successfully on?   I still have people on Win 2000 using my software

Comment: @MattMcNabb, IIRC, it was something like Windows 95 that was the last time `TCHAR` was actually useful.

Comment: @Matt Unicode binaries work with *all* versions of Windows NT. They do not work with Windows 9x/Me, unless you have the Unicode helper installed. So all apps complied nowadays should use Unicode. Of course, there's nothing wrong with using TCHAR and compiling with `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` defined (which is the default setting for new Visual Studio projects).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first pass a directory name to be searched recursively. Now for all subdirectories, you skip `.` and `..` and pass remaining **directory** name recursively to this function.

You never add `\*` to this directory name to make it a `patter` to seach recursively, which makes FindFirstFile to return this directory itself. (As the directory is the only one that mathes without pattern.) and hence the infinite recursion and stack overflow.

**Solution** You should append `\*` to to the directory name before calling you `getAllFiles` function recursively.

Comment: That's it! I was accessing current directory all time, that's why stack overflow, right?

Comment: And you posted it on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: @Jack There was a mistake in my previous analysis, I corrected it. I hope this analysis would be helpful for you.

Comment: @MohitJain: It was very helpful. I figured out another problem too. Check out my answer. (Also, I beging typying before I saw your re-post)

Comment: I accepted your answer and deleted mine. Makes more sense do it.

Answer (score 0):

You only test the `FindFirstFile` return value for `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. It may also return `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.